# Remover acentuação de uma string em linguagem C

Tags: c, array, string, char, caracteres

Estou com um trabalho da faculdade sobre `Threads` e controle de concorrência (OpenMP) em C, que está me dando um pouco de dor de cabeça.

O trabalho consiste em pegar um texto de um arquivo qualquer e separá-lo entre `Threads` produtoras e consumidoras, onde as consumidoras irão contar a ocorrência de uma palavra em uma linha e contabilizar em uma variável compartilhada entre as threads.

O problema nem está no foco principal que são as `Threads` e o próprio controle, mas no pré-processamento do texto, eu tenho que retirar acentuações e caracteres especiais.

Eu já tentei de toda maneira mas não consegui mapear as duas posições de char (wchar que são definidas, se não me engano) que guardam esse tipo de carácter. Alguém já fez alguma conversão do tipo?

A comparação direta não funciona e nem usando "strcmp".  Pode me auxiliar? Lembrando que é em C e não C++.

Em suma, dado uma string em C, é preciso remover acentuações e caracteres especiais como exemplo:

```
char texto[] = "téxtô açentûádo";

//processo de remoção de acentos e caracteres especiais.  
puts(texto); //retorna "texto acentuado" ao invés de "téxtô açentûádo"
```

Comment: Creio que esta pergunta foi fechada indevidamente pelo motivo que foi dado. Ela não é ampla demais, entretanto acredito que pode ter duplicatas por aí.